# How to store many Images to use on a Vue js website

Tags: image, vue.js, performance

I'm creating a vue js quiz website where every question will be connected to an image. I have a lot of questions for different quiz types and since every question will have an image I will end up with more than 1000 images. Now I store all images in the **assets** folder and I'm just testing with one quiz which has around 30 images and the app already loads quite slow. My question is, is there a way to store the images separately and just identify each image with an image path that is fetched from my backend?

Comment: You probably want to place the static image files in `/public` and reference them directly. See https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling

Comment: Hello @match, thank you for your advice, I will for sure implement it. Do you know what I can do with the ones that are not static?

Comment: What about creating an s3 bucket on AWS?

Comment: Hello rguttersohn, thank you for your comment. Can you tell me more about how it works?